# Как передать данные из dataGridView одной формы в другой dataGridView на другой форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть у меня приложение на WINForms, Вот хочу реализовать такой функционал, на главной форме выводятся данные в dataGridView1,я при клике на нужную мне строку, открываю новая форма и мне нужно предать эту выделенную строку в эту форму, для простоты пусть будет тоже dataGridView2. Подскажите где не так думаю,почему не работает.
Вот сама 1 форма.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Какая то логика заполения DataGrid
            List<Data> list=new List<Data>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                list.Add(new Data(){Id = 01,Name = "Иван",Description = "Jgbcfybt"});
                list.Add(new Data() { Id = 02, Name = "Николай", Description = "Другое описание" });
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
            // пусть выделяется сразу строка.
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }


      // обработчик события двойного клика на строку в DataGrid
        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // при клике на строку мне нужно  открыть новую форму и пердать туда выделенную строку

           var b= dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
            Form2 f2 = new Form2(b); // создаю форму

          f2.Show();


        }
    }
}
```

Вот вторая форма.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2(DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dataGridViewSelectedRowCollection)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            dataGridView1.DataSource= dataGridViewSelectedRowCollection;
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Ваша форма2 содержит 1 конструктор, который с параметром, а вы её пытаетесь создать, вызывая конструктор без параметров. Потому, я думаю, у вас ничего не компилируется. Я бы на вашем месте передавал бы туда просто `dataGridView1.SelectedRows` без всяких танцев с коллбеками/делегатами

Comment: `... почему не работает` Для начала напишите что именно происходит. Если возникают ошибки, то попробуйте разобраться с ними по одной прежде чем переходить к полному заданию.

Comment: @tym32167 Убрал все лишнее просто перtдаю в конструктор 2 формы object sender но  на 2 форме пусто

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch словесное описание кода бесполезно. Если у вас проблемы с кодом - показывайте код (в вопросе), а не его текстовое описание.

Comment: @tym32167 поправил код, при запуске на второй форме DataGridView не заполнен

Comment: А вы можете пояснить, что ваш новый код должен делать? Почему он вообще что то должен показать? Что за тип у объекта `sender` что вы передаете во вторую форму? Он вообще пригоден для того, чтобы быть источником данных?

Comment: @tym32167 В отладчике я вижу что содержится в сендере. Код делает простое, на первой форме по нажатию на кнопку заполняется Datagidview, далее по клику на сроку в Datagridview,открывается вторая форма  в которой есть datagridview и в него нужно вывести выделенную строку из datagridview  из первой формы в datagridview во второй форме

Comment: `нужно вывести выделенную строку из datagridview из первой формы` - так вы этого нигде не делаете. Где у вас передача выделенных строк во вторую форму? `sender` - определенно не то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @tym32167 Сейчас подправил код, выводится теперь на втором датагриде во второй форме только почему то служебная информация, но не сама выделенная строка,вернее не инфа из нее

Comment: Теперь вижу проблему, замените `var b= dataGridView1.SelectedRows;` на `var b= dataGridView1.SelectedRows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Select(x=>x.DataBoundItem).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замените

```
var b= dataGridView1.SelectedRows;
```

на

```
var b= dataGridView1.SelectedRows
            .OfType<DataGridViewRow>()
            .Select(x=>(Data)x.DataBoundItem)
            .ToArray();
```

После этого можно переделать конструктор второй формы на

```
public Form2(Data[] data)        
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало, Я как раз и думал, как мне вытащить нужные данные,я же их видел , но не хватило опыта,Спасибо.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch пожалуйста